# is WSAASyncSelect good enough? Could you suggest an alternative? Is Indy better?

Tags: delphi, indy

I never liked components for winsock programming,I loved it in its natural way,but today my collegue told me to use Indy for my project.Could you tell me if Indy better alternative  for my project?
-2 TCP servers,2 TCP clients.4 sockets total
-The project is a proxy.

And now the second question,I read daily that WSAASyncSelect is not good and that's predictable,it's from winsock 1.1.My question is: Suggest something better than AsyncSelect for winsock-by-hand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference tends to lean on [synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/download) for all of my socket work because of its light and easy to understand approach.  It is not a component architecture, but a class architecture and implementation is generally as simple as copying one of the existing helper classes and modifying it to perform the exact steps needed.  Synapse also has a great user community, and is being actively developed so get the latest changes from the svn snapshot (I believe its revision 98, the website has a zip of revision 38).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Indy is much better because it provides you with consistent abstraction of winsock communication. The difference is like creation windows using WinApi and simply using TForm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Indy is better. So is ICS, or Synapse, or any of the other internet-related component sets. They handle all of the minutia and let you work on your application's actual functionality instead of wasting your time on the communications layer details. They're also much more well tested (because of the broader user base and wider range of hardware and operating systems) than your own code could ever hope to be.

NIH (Not Invented Here) is a really bad idea if there are well-constructed, well-maintained, and widely used alternatives available, especially when those alternatives are free with source (like Indy and ICS).